# Loading keras model into tensorspace

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I understand that I have to visualize my model I have to follow to steps: 1) Preprocessing the pre-trained model (lets assume it's called my_model.h5) and 2.) creation of the interactive model.

Further I have created a json file of my model as mentioned within the instructions (Model Preprocessing):https://tensorspace.org/html/docs/preKeras.html

I have node.js installed and I installed tensorspace via `npm install tensorspace`. However I'm not able to recall the API of tensorspace. Does anyone now if I missed something out?